# AspNetCore React can only find spa files in dev mode

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp-net-core-spa-services

My AspNetCore/React project works fine in the Development environment but as soon as I run it in any other environment I get `System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.`

The end of the startup.cs configure method looks like this

```cs
      app.UseSpa(spa =>
      {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
          spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
      });
```

but since this is identical to the corresponding code in the app generated by `dotnet new react` I suppose something else is upsetting it.

The webserver does start and I can access Swagger pages. It's just the app proper that can't be found. Hacking the above code so that `spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");`runs causes the app to be found for all environments (environment specific config is loaded) but served by the React dev server.

I would have *said* this line

```cs
spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
```

was what governs the finding of `/index.html` and friends, but something is preventing them from being found.

What else I should look at?

I've seen this [The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865884) but I don't think this is the problem I'm facing.

A search of the project reveals than there is only one file `index.html` and it is located in `ClientApp/public`. The Configure method starts like this

```
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days...
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
```

Comment: React is not a .Net application.  These is no point to host it with IIS nor Kestrel because it's not dynamic from the server.  The reason it even exists as a SPA middleware is for development purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React assets are not built by `dotnet build` or `dotnet run` not even with `-c Release`.

To also build the React assets you need `dotnet publish`.

This requirement may be masked by the presence of assets due to earlier use of `dotnet publish`. In that case they are potentially stale. Therefore, for any environment other than dev, you **must** use `dotnet publish`.

Why don't `dotnet build` and `dotnet run` build the React assets? In development you don't need them because you're using the dev server for hot swap. In production you're almost certainly using assets prepared by `dotnet publish`.

Why did I not remember this? I almost never *do* builds for environments other than dev. I don't build for production, CICD does that. Professional testers are more likely to be aware of this than programmers simply because they build for environments other than dev.